# Translate this equation... Please

Tags: java, swing, math, equation

I have this here Final Exam Calculator app I wrote in java, but I cant get the math right.

Here is my Code

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MyFirstApp {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


    try {
        // Set System L&F
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} 
catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
   // handle exception
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   // handle exception
}
catch (InstantiationException e) {
   // handle exception
}
catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
   // handle exception
}

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MyFirstApp window = new MyFirstApp();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public MyFirstApp() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 342, 281);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c=e.getKeyChar();
            if(!(Character.isDigit(c) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)) {
                e.consume();
            }

        }

    });



    textField.setBounds(88, 37, 150, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c=e.getKeyChar();
            if(!(Character.isDigit(c) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) 
                    || c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)) {

                e.consume();

            }
        }
    });
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(88, 84, 150, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c=e.getKeyChar();
            if(!(Character.isDigit(c) || (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)) {
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    });
    textField_2.setColumns(10);
    textField_2.setBounds(127, 129, 71, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_2);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Calculate");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String gradestring = textField.getText();
            String wantstring = textField_1.getText();
            String finalstring = textField_2.getText();

            int gradeparse = Integer.parseInt(gradestring);
            int wantparse = Integer.parseInt(wantstring);
            int finalpercentage = Integer.parseInt(finalstring);



            int findworthpercentage = finalpercentage;
            int showfinal = 

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is what you need " + showfinal/100);

        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(116, 181, 101, 39);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JLabel lblGrade = new JLabel("Grade:");
    lblGrade.setBounds(45, 40, 43, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblGrade);

    JLabel lblWant = new JLabel("Want:");
    lblWant.setBounds(45, 87, 33, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblWant);

    JLabel lblWorth = new JLabel("Worth:");
    lblWorth.setBounds(85, 132, 43, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblWorth);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("%");
    label.setBounds(202, 132, 11, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);

    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("%");
    label_1.setBounds(242, 87, 11, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label_1);

    JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("%");
    label_2.setBounds(242, 40, 11, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label_2);
}
}
```

The place where I need the math to work is the int showfinal. Here is the equation:

> Grade = Exam Worth × Exam Score + (1 – Exam Worth) × Current Grade

I need help translating this into my project.
Thanks, sorry for bad English.

Comment: Where are you trying to implement stated equation. In `btnNewButton.addActionListener` ?

Comment: Hey, I am trying to implement the equation under the method  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e). I want to print the result in a messageDialogBox and so I am going to need to store the result of the equation in the variable int showfinal.

Comment: Please look at the [help] as well as [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how you can improve this question and increase your odds of getting decent answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:
`int showfinal`
have it be a double for more correct answers:
`double showfinal`

Then, assuming Current Grade is a percentage, such as 95 (A), here is the equation that works:

```
double showfinal = (wantparse/100.0 - ((1 - findworthpercentage/100.0) * gradeparse/100.0)) / (findworthpercentage/100.0);
showfinal = Math.round(showfinal*100.0)/100.0;
```

Then, if you want to display a percentage, change:
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is what you need " + showfinal/100);`

To multiplication of 100, instead:
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is what you need " + showfinal*100);`

If you want a decimal, do not multiply by 100.

If I understood your intention, this equation will yield, as an example:

```
gradeparse = 85 //Current Grade percentage
wantparse = 90 //Grade wanted percentage
findworthpercentage = 50 //Final is worth half of overall grade

showfinal = 0.95 //Grade needed in Final. Again, multiply by 100 for the percentage.
```

Comment: This worked like a freaking charm! I know this is pretty basic stuff, but kinda of a neat program given that I started learning java a day ago. Huge Thanks man!

Comment: @TheHoop No problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

so,
findworthpercentage = exam worth?
wantparse = exam score?
gradeparse = current grade?

if it is, then:

```
showfinal = findworthpercentage * wantparse + ( 1 - findworthpercentage ) * gradeparse;
```

your variables usage & naming are a bit confusing